# Jquery form post Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I am using asp.net MVC and I am having an issue posting a form using jquery.
It is not posting to the url I am telling it to.
If I use firebug, it shows the post happening but it is posting to the index of the controller everytime. I cannot figure out why. I have verified the url of the action I am trying to post but I can't figure out why it is always posting to the index of the controller....Note: the view in which the form is found IS the index view. so Basically it is posting to it's own action rather than the one in the url i am telling it to. Any help would be great. thanks!

here is my form

```
 <form  action='' id="descriptionForm">
<%=Html.Hidden("claimNumber", ViewData["claimNumber"])%>
<%=Html.Hidden("partNumber", ViewData["partNumber"])%>
<%=Html.Hidden("qty", ViewData["qty"])%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            Category:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.DropDownList("problemCategory", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["problemSelect"], "-Select-")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            Details:
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="problemDetails">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            Dealer Notes:
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextArea("dealerNotes", "", 3, 40, null)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 8px; right: 8px">
    <input type="button" id="itemDetailsCancel" value="Cancel" />
    <input type="submit" id="itemDetailsSubmit" value="Save" />
</div>
</form>
 <a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Warranty/WarrantyClaims/CompleteAddLineItemToClaim/") %>'
id="CompleteLineItemUrl"></a>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
   $("#descriptionForm").submit(function () {
    var completeurl = $("#CompleteLineItemUrl").attr('href');
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post({
        type:'POST',
        url: completeurl,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("done");
        }
    });
    return false
});
```

and just for good measure here is the controller action I am trying to post to(though it doesn't do much yet)

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompleteAddLineItemToClaim(string claimNumber, string partNumber, string qty, string problemCategory, string problemDetails, string dealerNotes)
    {
        var result = new { result = "done" };

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Update: 
updated javascript

```
$(function(){

        $('#descriptionForm').submit(function () {
            var completeurl = $('#CompleteLineItemUrl').attr('href');
            var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: completeurl,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('done');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the form itself loaded by an ajax call?

If so you need to use the live() function of jquery.

Comment: This fixed it!!! Thank you. i used  $("#descriptionForm").live("submit", function () { and the function above with the .post exampe darin gave and It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have wrapped your javascript in a `document.ready` before subscribing for any events. Also you have a missing `;` when returning false at the end of your method.

But your real problem is that you want to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). So what actually happens is that you are getting a javascript error because of wrongly using the `$.post` function and the `.submit` handler never has time to `return false` and cancel the default submission of the form and the browser happily proceeds into POSTing to the action of the form (which is empty and default to the action that rendered this form).

So to sum up:

```
$(function() {
    $('#descriptionForm').submit(function () {
        var completeurl = $('#CompleteLineItemUrl').attr('href');
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: completeurl,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert('done');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or if you wanted to use `$.post`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#descriptionForm').submit(function () {
        var completeurl = $('#CompleteLineItemUrl').attr('href');
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.post(completeurl, data, function (result) {
            alert('done');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also instead of generating links à la classic WebForms way:

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Warranty/WarrantyClaims/CompleteAddLineItemToClaim/") %>' id="CompleteLineItemUrl"></a>
```

In ASP.NET MVC you use HTML helpers in order to ensure that link urls are conform to your routes:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Link text", 
    "CompleteAddLineItemToClaim", 
    "WarrantyClaims", 
    new { area = "Warranty" },
    new { id = "CompleteLineItemUrl" }
) %>
```

Comment: thanks for catching the missing ';' it is there now. I made the changes to my javascript as posted above and it still is posting to the index action. See anything else I am still doing wrong?

Comment: @twaldron, so which one of the two versions are you using? `$.ajax` or `$.post`?

Comment: @twaldron, are you getting some other javascript errors? You could use FireBug to put breakpoints in your javascript and step through the code to see which line breaks. Also where are you writing this javascript? Is it inline or in a separate js file? If it is in a separate file have you included it? Also have you referenced jQuery in your project? Did you ensure about correct paths for those scripts?

Comment: @Darrin Dimitrov Now that you say that I am seeing that it is not even entering my .submit function, which explains why it is posting back to the index action. I will figure out why it is not entering the function now.right now it is in the same file as the html. jquery is working(if i change one of the buttons to .button() it works. as does $.show(), and $.hide()

Comment: @twaldron, might be because you have a javascript error somewhere else, you haven't included jQuery, you are not running this script in a document.ready handler, ... there are many possibilities. FireBug is your friend.

Comment: I will figure it from here i think and post back what I find. thank you!